# No 'Tools' Option for Visual Studio Code \\The menu bar is missing it

Tags: visual-studio-code

Across the top I see:
[File  Edit  Selection  View  Go  Debug  Terminal  Help]
No Tools options.  And some of the things I was trying to do, like reset to default settings, I can only do through that option. 
Here is the info about my version (yes i have checked for updates)

[image]

Answer (score 32):

If some other noob like me shows up looking for a "Tool" dropdown menu you should stop looking : it does not exist in `Visual Studio Code` but it does in `Visual Studio`... not the same software, almost same name.

Answer (score 5):

You can reset your settings in "File" -> "Preferences" -> "Settings" -> Top right corner: 3 dots, click on them -> "Show modified settings" -> "User settings"/"Workspace settings" -> Click on the gear right to the feature-tree and select "Reset Setting".

Are you missing something else ?

Comment: No, thats it.  Thank you